# Upload image file to laravel api from android

Tags: android, http-post, apache-httpasyncclient, laravel-api

I am not able to understand how could I upload image file from my android device to Laravel API with POST data, I am already sending some text data to API using android-asynchronous-http-client but it's not working with Image files. The API end works fine I tested it using POSTMAN but gives error on android device `status code: 500 Internal Server Error`

**ANDROID PART**

```
            RequestParams ComplaintsDataRequestParams = new RequestParams();

            ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Complaint_Subject", complaintsSubject.getText().toString());
            ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Complaint_Details", complaintsDetails.getText().toString());
            ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Complaint_Address", complaintAddress.getText().toString());
            ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Username", HomeActivity.home_username);
            ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Complainant_CNIC", HomeActivity.user_cnic);
            ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Complaint_id", uniqueComplaintID);
            ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("User_Location", user_complete_address + "-" + lat + "," + lng);

            if (ImageEvidence1 != null) {
                evidenceID1 = uniqueComplaintID + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis();
                ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Evidence_ID1", "YES");
                ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Evidence_ID1_name", evidenceID1);
                ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Evidence_ID1_data", ImageEvidence1);
            }
            if (ImageEvidence2 != null) {
                evidenceID2 = uniqueComplaintID + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis();
                ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Evidence_ID2", "YES");
                ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Evidence_ID2_name", evidenceID2);
                ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Evidence_ID2_data", ImageEvidence2);
            }
            if (ImageEvidence3 != null) {
                evidenceID3 = uniqueComplaintID + "-" + System.currentTimeMillis();
                ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Evidence_ID3", "YES");
                ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Evidence_ID3_name", evidenceID3);
                ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Evidence_ID3_data", ImageEvidence3);
            }



Complaints_REST_API_Client.POST("?action=store", ComplaintsDataRequestParams, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "200 OK"
                complaint_confirmation();
                Log.d("newComplaintActivity", "statusCode " + statusCode);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable error) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
                submittingComplaint.dismiss();
                Log.d("newComplaintActivity", "statusCode " + statusCode);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Exception: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

  });
```

The `ImageEvidence` is a `Uri` type variable which is used in `imageView.setImageURI(ImageEvidence)` and `evidenceID` are just the names for image files.

**LARAVEL API PART**

```
            Complaint::create([
                'title' => $request->input('Complaint_Subject'),
                'description' => $request->input('Complaint_Details'),
                'address' => $request->input('Complaint_Address'),
                'firebase_user_id' => $request->input('Username'),
                'firebase_user_cnic' => $request->input('Complainant_CNIC'),
                'firebase_complaint_id' => $request->input('Complaint_id'),
                'firebase_user_location' => $request->input('User_Location'),
                'status' => 'pending'
            ]);

            if ($request->input('Evidence_ID1') == "YES")
                Evidence::create([
                    'evidence_name' => $request->input('Evidence_ID1_name'),
                    'eivdence_image' => $request->file('Evidence_ID1_data')->store('public/evidences'),
                    'complaint_id' => $request->input('Complaint_id')
                ]);

            if ($request->input('Evidence_ID2') == "YES")
                Evidence::create([
                    'evidence_name' => $request->input('Evidence_ID2_name'),
                    'eivdence_image' => $request->file('Evidence_ID2_data')->store('public/evidences'),
                    'complaint_id' => $request->input('Complaint_id')
                ]);

            if ($request->input('Evidence_ID3') == "YES")
                Evidence::create([
                    'evidence_name' => $request->input('Evidence_ID3_name'),
                    'eivdence_image' => $request->file('Evidence_ID3_data')->store('public/evidences'),
                    'complaint_id' => $request->input('Complaint_id')
                ]);
```

Please tell me which library should I use to send Image file along with POST data.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by a very simple shortcut method

as I were requesting file at API end but I was sending Uri i.e. `ImageEvidence1`. So the simple hack was that I got the absolute path of URI and put it into file and then

```
File file = new File(new URI(ImageEvidence1.getPath()));
ComplaintsDataRequestParams.put("Evidence_ID3_data", file);
```

So this was it.